# Acrescentando valor no picturebox

Tags: c#, while, picturebox

eu gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de fazer isso aqui funcionar

```
int chck = 0;
int fid = 0;
        while (chck < 150)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                string sql2 = "SELECT img FROM clienteimg WHERE ((clienteid = '" + cid + "') AND (id = '" + fid + "'))";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, sqlcon);
                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                dr2.Read();
                byte[] imgLoc = (byte[])dr2[0];
                sqlcon.Close();
                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgLoc);
                pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                sqlcon.Close();
                sqlcon.Open();
                string foid = "9";
                string sql3 = "SELECT img FROM ClienteImgDB WHERE id = '" + foid + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, sqlcon);
                SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                dr3.Read();
                byte[] imgLoc = (byte[])dr3[0];
                sqlcon.Close();
                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgLoc);
                pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
            }
            chck++;
            fid++;
        }
```

sendo que, ali no  pb1.Image (picturebox1 pra quem não entendeu), eu queria que o numero fosse flexivel, eu sei que o exemplo a seguir não funciona, mas espero que entendam onde quero chegar

```
int chck = 0;
int fid = 0;
        while (chck < 150)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                string sql2 = "SELECT img FROM clienteimg WHERE ((clienteid = '" + cid + "') AND (id = '" + fid + "'))";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, sqlcon);
                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                dr2.Read();
                byte[] imgLoc = (byte[])dr2[0];
                sqlcon.Close();
                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgLoc);
                pb'"+fid+"'.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                sqlcon.Close();
                sqlcon.Open();
                string foid = "9";
                string sql3 = "SELECT img FROM ClienteImgDB WHERE id = '" + foid + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, sqlcon);
                SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                dr3.Read();
                byte[] imgLoc = (byte[])dr3[0];
                sqlcon.Close();
                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgLoc);
                pb'"+fid+"'.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
            }
            chck++;
            fid++;
        }
```

pra que toda vez que rode o loop, o "pb" se acrescente em mais 1 para preencher os 150 pictureboxes que tenho

Comment: Vendo o código e mesmo você explicando, não entendi o que você quer dizer com número flexível. Qual é o erro específico que você está encontrando? Você quer criar objetos dinamicamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `Find` do controle ou form em que estão inseridos os picturebox:

```
for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ((PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("pb" + i, true)[0]).Image = null;
}
```

ps. Tenha certeza que existe o controle, caso contrário receberá uma exception.

---

Outra opção, seria gerar os controles dentro do loop, e então geraria somente a quantidade necessária (Eu faria dessa forma).

Considerando que os `PictureBox` estarão dentro do `panel1`:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Name = "pb" + i;
    pb.Image = null;
    pb.Parent = panel1;
    pb.Show();
}
```

---

**Edit:**

A primeira opção, no seu código ficaria assim:

```
try
{
    sqlcon.Open();
    string sql2 = "SELECT img FROM clienteimg WHERE ((clienteid = '" + cid + "') AND (id = '" + fid + "'))";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, sqlcon);
    SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    dr2.Read();
    byte[] imgLoc = (byte[])dr2[0];
    sqlcon.Close();
    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgLoc);
    ((PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("pb" + fid , true)[0]).Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
}
...
```

> Lembrando que o nome do seu `PictureBox` deve ser "pb"+ [cada `fid` que você irá carregar]

A segunda opção, sim, terá que remover os PictureBox da tela, pois não servirão pra nada. A recomendação é que utilize um Panel ou FlowLayoutPanel para inserir todos os PictureBox dentro, dessa forma fica fácil organizar, limpar e inserir.

Mas, com a segunda opção, muda a lógica que você está usando, o `Select` seria diferente, entre outras coisas.

Comment: desculpa mas eu nunca usei isso, não entendi direito como encaixar o meu "try" dentro, estou tentando com sua segunda opção, outra coisa, os pb que tenho então devo deletar né?, pelo que entendi o código ai cria um pb toda vez, correto?

Comment: com a permissão do colega, editei a resposta explicando como entraria no seu código. Espero que ajude.

Comment: deu certo, só ficou meio lento pq tem 150, mas pode ser o meu pc, de resto ficou top, vlw ai (: